# regex to match a line but don't include the string in output

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse SQL query join condition . I need to extract the line line which contains `(+)` and also group it based on extract . I am using python 3.6

Below are my test strings :

```
  1.  a.deptno = b.dept_no(+)
  2.  c.deptno(+)=b.dept_no
  3.  a.deptno(+)= 900
```

> First : I need to extract lines which has `(+)` second : Need to
>   extract the alias for example

```
1. a , b
2. c , b
3. a
```

Till now I have tried [regex](https://regex101.com/r/cScAbv/1)

Using `([\w_]+).*?([\w_]+)\(\+\)` I am able to extract first group but second group seems to have some issue .

Any advice will be really helpful

Comment: seems `.*?` is not understood correctly what do you want to match with it maybe `\W+` or just `\.`

Comment: You could try it with a lookahead [`^(?=.*\(\+\))(\w+)\.[^=]+=\s*(?:(\w+)\.)?.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/wMxunl/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks you so much this solves my need . if you can help me understand in answer :) will mark is answered . Thank you once again

Comment: @ciprian I have added this answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do it use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=` to assert that the string contains `(+)`.

Then you could match your values in a capturing group.

[`^(?=.*\(\+\))(\w+)\.[^=]+=\s*(?:(\w+)\.)?.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/wMxunl/1/)

**That would match:**

- `^` The start of the line
- `(?=.*\(\+\))` Positive lookahead that asserts that what follows contains `(+)`
- `(\w+)\.` Capture in a group one or more word characters (**group 1**) followed by a dot
- `[^=]+` Match NOT an = sign one or more times
- `=\s*` Match an = sign and after that zero or more white space characters
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(\w+)\.` Capture in a group one or more word characters (**group 2**) followed by a dot
- `)?` Close the non capturing group and make it optional
- `.*$` match any character zero or more times until the end of the line `$`

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = r'([a-z]+)\.[a-z]+\_?[a-z]+\(\+\)'

In [24]: s  = 'a.deptno = b.dept_no(+)'
In [25]: re.search(pattern, s).group(1)
Out[25]: 'b'

In [26]: s = "c.deptno(+)=b.dept_no"
In [27]: re.search(pattern, s).group(1)
Out[27]: 'c'

In [28]: s = "a.deptno(+)= 900"
In [29]: re.search(pattern, s).group(1)
Out[29]: 'a'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks . I need group1 and group2 output(if exists) . for example for out1-> should be `a` and `b` Out2: c and b and out3: a